# Amazon Alexa "SpeechletResponse was null"

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

This is not through any third-party code editor. This is through the Alexa Developer Console.

I am trying to create a skill for my school to get the current updates if the school is closed, two-hour delay, etc.

This is the code that handles it:

```js
const GetCurrentUpdateHandler = {
    canHandle(handlerInput) {
        return Alexa.getRequestType(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'IntentRequest'
            && Alexa.getIntentName(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'GetCurrentUpdate'
    },
    handle(handlerInput) {
        let speakOutput = ""
        axios.get("District Link")
            .then(res => {
                const dom = new JSDOM(res.data)
                const msgs = dom.window.document.getElementById("onscreenalert-ctrl-msglist")
                const useless = msgs.querySelectorAll("input")
                useless.forEach(function (el) {
                    el.parentNode.removeChild(el)
                })
                const message = msgs.innerText
                if (message === undefined) {
                    console.log("no messages")
                    speakOutput = "There are currently no messages."
                    finishReq(speakOutput)
                } else {
                    console.log("message")
                    speakOutput = `Here is a message from District. ${msgs.innerText}`
                    finishReq(speakOutput)
                }
            })
        function finishReq(output) {
            return handlerInput.responseBuilder
                .speak(output)
                .getResponse();
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting a "SpeechletResponse was null" error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things...

1. Because of the promise on `axios.get`, the function itself could be terminating and returning nothing before the promise is fulfilled.

   Consider using `async-await` to pull the results of the `axios.get` call synchronously.
2. `finishReq` returns the response builder to the function that called it, not as the result of the handler. So even if you use `async-await`, wrapping the handler return in a function redirects it and doesn't return it to the SDK for transmission to Alexa.

So:

```
async handle(handlerInput)
const res = await axios.get(...)
```

Unwrap the `.then` and `finishReq` code so it's all in the handler scope.

Answer (score 1):

For others who may find this post, your handler isn’t returning anything,; that's why you're getting the error.

You need:

```
return axios.get("District Link")
            .then(res => {
```

and

```
return finishReq(speakOutput)
```

for the two places you call `finishReq`.

Comment: Wow! Thank you for the response. It's a little late, but this will definitely help others when they get this error, because it's so ambiguous